# Why can't I connect 2 signal generators in series?

Tags: signal, kirchhoffs-laws, function-generator

I am about doing a laboratory about signal generators, and there is a question which 50% the people I talk say "Yes", and other 50% say "No".

Is it possible to connect 2 signal generators?

If you're able to help me, relate your answer with the basic circuit laws, instead of telling me examples, because I need a theoretical explanation of that.

Comment: What kind of signal generators? Lab bench-top generators likely have one side grounded, which would prevent them being connected in series. Generators that are specifically designed to be isolated or "floating" could be connected in series.

Comment: -1 for telling us how you want your answer and expecting that to be circuit laws (what are those anyway). Electronics is a lot about understanding **how** things work. The fact that you get 50/50 answers in your environment means to me that most of you have no clue. And that makes me sad. And no you cannot series connect signal generators. At least I have never seen one where that would be possible in over 25 years in electronics.

Comment: Are these bench/rack instruments? If so, I am having trouble understanding how it’s physically possible to connect them in series, unless they have specific ports for daisy-chaining units. In any event, if you are trying for a superposition, use a power combiner (eg. https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/Splitters.html)

Comment: Yes - you can connect everything you want. However - WHY? What do you expect from such doing?

Comment: Use a summing circuit

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to connect two signal generators in series. Here's an example circuit simulated in [LTspice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/). R1 and R2 represent the output impedance of each generator, and R3 is the load.:-

[image]

And here's the output of that simulation. You can see that the 50Hz and 60Hz signals have added together to produce a complex waveform:-

[image]

Note that the second generator is 'floating' ie. not connected to ground. Therefore the 'ground' side of that generator will have the first generator's output impressed on it. Depending on how the signal is coupled internally, that may mean that the entire generator (including case) is 'live', producing EMI which could affect nearby circuits.

If the second generator's output is already connected to ground internally then it will be a problem, because the first generator is then shorted to ground:-

[image]

If both generators are internally connected to ground you can still wire them in series, but only by their ground sides and only if the *load* is floating:-

[image]

Another thing to note is that the output impedances of the generators are also added. This could be problem if the load requires matched impedance to prevent reflections (eg. when sending high frequencies down a long cable).